# Set programmatically sessionState and httpCookies properties

Tags: asp.net, web-config, session-state

Our project has two elements in web.config: httpCookies and sessionState. We would like to have more controll on them and set them programmatically. The reason of this is for some specific requests we wanted to use different settings than for others. Is this possible?